# Adding each item from for loop to csv file

Tags: powershell, foreach

I am trying to use power shell to determine whether a server has a particular patch installed based on the KB and if not append the name to a csv. my input file has system names so I want to export that system name if it does not find the patch installed.

here is what i  have so far. The export to csv part does not seem to work.

```
forEach-Object{
    try{
        $status = wmic /node:@sys.csv qfe list full /format:table | findstr /i $kb_number

        if(!$status){
            $output_file = New-Item C:\temp\$kb_number.csv -ItemType File
            export-csv $output_file -append -Force
        }
        else{
            write-output $status
        }
    }
    catch{
        $error_message = $_.Exception.Message

        #write-output "the error message is" $error_message

        write-output "Could not find any system with this patch installed."
    }

}
```

Comment: Please [format your code properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Why your code might be failing**

We don't see where you're setting the values of `@sys.csv` or `$kb_number` in the code you shared.  Either of those could be throwing you off.

But the real issue is `Export-Csv`.  For one, you're making a new CSV with every iteration of the loop.  And for two, you have to pass in some item for the cmdlet to export as a CSV.  Right now, you're only providing these values.

```
$output_file = New-Item C:\temp\$kb_number.csv -ItemType File
Export-csv -Path $output_file -append -Force
```

`Export-Csv` requires an input object.  You're not giving it one now.

What do you want to export?  If you just want a list of computers without a patch, do this instead.

```
if(-not(Test-path C:\temp\$kb_number.csv)){
  #if file doesn't exist, make it
  $output_file = New-Item C:\temp\$kb_number.txt -ItemType File
}

#adds computer name if it doesn't have the patch
Add-Content -Path $output_file -Value $computer
```

**General Suggestions**

Instead of using `ForEach-Object`, you might find it's easier to debug if you use a `ForEach` loop like this.

```
$computers = Get-Content C:\pathTo\Your\ComputerList.txt
ForEach($computer in $computers){

}
```

One additional source of trouble is that your code is using older dos commands in `WMIC` and then tries to use PowerShell to store the records.  You don't need to do this and can make it easier on yourself if you swap out the calls to `wmic` for `Get-WmiObject` or `Get-CimInstance`, the PowerShell native versions of the commands.

To do that, change this line:

```
wmic /node:@sys.csv qfe list full /format:table  | findstr /i $kb_number
```

translates into

```
$kb_number = "KB4576484"
Get-CimInstance Win32_QuickFixEngineering -Filter "HotfixID = '$kb_number'" -ComputerName $computer 


Source        Description      HotFixID      InstalledBy          InstalledOn              
------        -----------      --------      -----------          -----------              
              Update           KB4576484     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  9/14/2020 12:00:00 AM
```

You can store the output of that in a variable and then call `Export-Csv` on it and that should work.

When in doubt, remove the filter part and just get it working to export all patches to a csv.  Then add complexity by adding back the filtering statements.